# Log4j2 does not create the logfile in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I have a Spring boot app and I want to use LOG4J2 to manage my logs in different files, but the logfile isn't created.

I have a log4j2.properties configuration under "resources"

My log file configuration:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
#output folder
property.filename=G:\\PRUEBAS
property.packagename=com.package.main
appenders=console, infoLoggerAppender, commonLoggerAppender, errorLoggerAppender
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#common appender
appender.commonLoggerAppender.type=File
appender.commonLoggerAppender.name=RollingFile
appender.commonLoggerAppender.fileName=${filename}\\log.log
appender.commonLoggerAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.commonLoggerAppender.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#error appender
appender.errorLoggerAppender.type=RandomAccessFile
appender.errorLoggerAppender.name=RandomAccessFile
appender.errorLoggerAppender.fileName=${filename}\\error.log
appender.errorLoggerAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.errorLoggerAppender.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#using LevelRangeFilter to only log error levels.
appender.errorLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.type=LevelRangeFilter
appender.errorLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.minLevel=error
appender.errorLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.maxLevel=error
#info appender
appender.infoLoggerAppender.type=File
appender.infoLoggerAppender.name=LOGFILE
appender.infoLoggerAppender.fileName=${filename}\\info.log
appender.infoLoggerAppender.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.infoLoggerAppender.layout.info=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#using LevelRangeFilter to only log info levels.
appender.infoLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.type=LevelRangeFilter
appender.infoLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.minLevel=info
appender.infoLoggerAppender.filter.threshold.maxLevel=info
# creating only one logger, we can use this with multiple appenders.
loggers=fileLogger
# this is package name. This package and all of it's child packages will use this logger
logger.fileLogger.name=${packagename}
# logger base level
logger.fileLogger.level=debug
logger.fileLogger.appenderRefs=infoLoggerAppender, commonLoggerAppender, errorLoggerAppender
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.infoLoggerAppender.ref=LOGFILE
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.commonLoggerAppender.ref=RollingFile
logger.fileLogger.appenderRef.errorLoggerAppender.ref=RandomAccessFile
rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
```

What can I do? Someone can help me?
I waste my last two days with this...

Comment: In a Maven or Gradle project the usual location for that file is under `src/main/resources`, not `resources`.

Comment: It is on src/main/resources, sorry if I not explain

Comment: In line - `logger.fileLogger.name=${packagename}`  correct ? Is there any actual packagename that exist in your application or you have written as it is ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the log4j2 jar is available in sprint boot application if not then add the maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Create Log4j2.properties file and declare all the 
Create that file inside the resource folder

```
    name = ABC 
    appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.fileName = ABClog/ABCapplication.log
    appender.rolling.filePattern = ABClog/ABCapplication.%d{dd-MMM}.log
    appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
    appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l]- %msg%n
    appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
    appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy 
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete 
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath =log 
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ABC*.log
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.type = IfAny
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 14d
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
    appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 200MB

    appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
    appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
    appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

    logger.rolling.name = com.currentobject.controller
    logger.rolling.level = debug
    logger.rolling.additivity = false
    logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

provide the path of log4j2.properties file into the application.properties file

```
    logging.config=classpath:properties/log4j2.properties
```